# If multiple players must make a choice, in what order are the choices made?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, if [Merciless Executioner](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Merciless%20Executioner) enters the battlefield, and both players have multiple creatures, which player chooses a creature to sacrifice first? Obviously the latter will have an advantage. Technically it can't be done simultaneously, so who should go first?

Comment: Technically, the choosing *can* be done simultaneously. But it's not. As for the actual sacrifice, they are performed simultaneously as far s the game is concerned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When multiple players must make a choice simultaneously, they do so in "Active Player, Non Active Player" order. This means that first, the player currently taking their turn chooses, then each other player chooses in turn order.

[Rule 101.4](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Magic_Golden_Rules) says

> If multiple players would make choices and/or take actions at the same time, the active player (the player whose turn it is) makes any choices required, then the next player in turn order (usually the player seated to the active player's left) makes any choices required, followed by the remaining nonactive players in turn order. Then the actions happen simultaneously. This rule is often referred to as the "Active Player, Nonactive Player (APNAP) order" rule.

Comment: How does this go with warp world?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It works the same with Warp World: you follow the instructions in order, and when multiple players need to make a choice, they do so in APNAP order. The [Warp World Gatherer rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=190187) have a good description of what exactly you do.